# Text editor that takes more than 10 gb

Tags: windows, text-editor, plain-text, text-processing, regex

I have Emeditor and it does what I want but when it has a file that has one or more gb, it slows down a little or doesn't do a lot. I wanted to know if there's a text-editor that has or does what Emeditor does, takes more than 10 gb and does a lot in less movement/time. What I do or want Emeditor to do is delete duplicated lines, sort lines, and use regex.

Comment: I doubt there will be text editors taking 10gb of file and letting your edit/process text. The reason for that is if the text editor reads entire 10gb, it will need a RAM of 10gb i.e. your system RAM should be around 12-13gb+.

Comment: You should state in your question which features you need. Assume that answerers don’t know Emeditor.

Answer (score 4):

There is a chance, that [**Sublime**](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) is suitable for your task, **but** with several prerequisites:

1. You should **disable** plugins such as *syntax highlighting*, *bracket matcher* or *git gutter*, i.e. any plugin that applies regexes to the edited text. Otherwise memory/CPU requrements will be unexpectedly high.
2. The file **must accept being split into lines**. Good example: a log file. Bad example: a binary file or file with base64-encoded content.

**Why it works with huge files**: Sublime uses [memory mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) under the hood. For us this means, that we don't need 10GB of RAM to edit 10GB file with Sublime.

I have edited files having about 500MB — worked good, with reasonable memory consumption (I mean, it doesn't eat more than 300MB).

Moreover, Sublime has an unlimited trial edition, but you could buy a license any time you want.

P.S. Sublime is good enough for many other text-related tasks.

Comment: Can you please clean up the paragraph explaining the use of memory mapping? As written it's unclear what you're saying.

Comment: Hmm, thanks! I've started to edit this paragraph, but seems, like I didn't finish editing and have pressed *Save*...

Comment: I have sublime but I think when I open big files, it stops working and goes away or closes. What will I do before I open big files? Do I just disable plugins? Does using regexes change anything or do something?

Comment: @user6779864, when you open large files Sublime applies all actions, required by plugin. Most _colorer, highlight, bracket matching_ are based on regular expressions. They works great, but when the file have sane size for **text** file. When the file is huge - regexes and other analysis engines takes a lot of extra memory and _probably_ CPU to do their job, because the file is extremely large. For example, try to open **diff** on github for massive file with a lot of changes - it will display a warning. Here is the similar case (not exact the same, but similar).

Comment: @user6779864, try to open file in pure Sublime. I am not sure about latest versions, but 3-4 month ago I didn't have any problem;)

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, Emacs (for Windows) and Sublime (*both free although there is a paid version for Sublime, but you don't need that*) would be your best bet.
I have opened 6GB files with Sublime without issues and without any modifications to the Sublime editor environment.  With Emacs you will probably need the package [vilf](https://github.com/m00natic/vlfi)  to open very large files.

[Emacs 25.1 (for Windows)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/emacsbinw64/?source=typ_redirect)

[Sublime 3](https://www.sublimetext.com/3)

Comment: I think I had Emacs before. Does Emacs show other characters/languages/letters? Does it delete duplicate lines and use regex?

Comment: Emacs supports a wide variety of international character sets.

Comment: Emacs can delete duplicate lines in many ways -- try M-x delete-duplicate-lines.  If that does not work, you can create a macro that deletes duplicate lines.  In Emacs you have regexp (regular expressions) available also -- see emacs wiki for further info at https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression.